# Google Maps Engine with a local MySql Server

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-engine

I want to use maps engine to show data in a map. The problem is that my data (kmz, csv, Mysql) is in a local server and because of internal politics I can't upload all this data to the cloud. I have seen that the Google Maps Engine API documentation talks about authentification for installed applications (https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/oauth/installedapplication). But does this mean that I can use Google Maps Engine locally? Can I use my local data in Google Maps Engine without uploading it to the cloud?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps Engine is a cloud based application. You must upload your data to GME in order to make use of it. The link you reference is for oAuth - an authentication mechanism to provide access to GME maps requiring a user account. An installed application is, for example, a Windows app that uses the Maps Engine API.
If you can get over your cloud issue, you could use the Maps Engine API to write a connector from mySQL to Maps Engine relatively easily

In your situation you should probably look at geoserver.